# Facebook Graph API Photo Call Issue

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am having problems when I call all of the photos it only listing/counting the first 25 tagged photos of a user from most recent back (test profile has 500 tagged)? Does anyone know if they use Pagination or what structure?

```
$profile = $facebook->api('/me/photos?access_token=' . $session['access_token']);
$count=count($profile['data']);
echo $count;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `print_r($profile)`? Facebook is definitely using pagination:

```
{
   "data": [
   ],
   "paging": {
      "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=XXXXXXX&limit=25&since=1301819990",
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=XXXXXXX&limit=25&until=1285072716"
   }
}
```